# How can I write a unit test for this asynchronous method?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, asynchronous, mockito

When I write unit tests for business code, I need to mock asynchronous thread calls and return a simulated result to save in the database. I don't know how to write unit test code for this method.

The tested code is as follows:

```
public void doWork(){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        FutureTask<TestVO> futureResult = null;

        futureResult = new FutureTask<TestVO>(new Callable<TestVO>() {
                public TestVO call() {
                    return testService.scan(_scan_params, finalProcess, _ywid, _logPath);
                }
            });

       executor.execute(futureResult);
       TestVO testVO = futureResult.get(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       TestRepository.save(testVO);
}
```

The method that needs to be mocked is as follows:

```
@Async("taskAccStepExecutor")
public TestVO scan(String params, String process, String ywid, String LogPath) {
       ......
       return testVO;
}
```

I used testng/mokito as a testing framework in my project.

My expectation is to simulate an asynchronous thread and return a custom testVO. This problem has troubled me for several days and I hope to get your help.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that the class that defines the doWork() method (let's call that class "Worker") gets the "testService" injected somehow and you have control over how that gets injected.

In that case, it would likely suffice if you create a Worker with a mocked testService in your unit test. Add when(testService.scan(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString()).thenReturn(new TestVO()) to mock what you are expecting from the service.
Then call the doWork method as that seems to be the method that you want to test.
Then verify that the scan method was called: verify(testService).scan(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString()).
Maybe also validate that the TestVO object was saved to your database.